# In JQuery is there a way to queue effects to occur after a time limit has expired?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, timer, jquery-effects

I'm trying to create a message notification for a web page using jQuery.  The message will slide up from the bottom and then after 10 seconds slide back down.  The problem is that I would like to setup the timing through the jQuery effects system if possible, rather than using `setTimeout`s.  Which is a rather inelegant solution?

How do you use jQuery to queue up effects to happen after certain time intervals?

Comment: What's the issue with setTimeout? Seems like the simple, elegant solution to what you want in my opinion; there's no point in over-engineering such a problem.

Comment: If there is a cleaner solution by plugging into the jquery effects system, then I would rather use that.  There are many common tasks that can be done with jQuery that can result in cleaner code than without using a library, and I'm curious if this is another case of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use delay function along with animation.
Check this URL: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function.

But ideally I would manage my own queue, invoking the next message when the current message closes (using the complete callback no `setTimeout` required)

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the callback on .animate() too to queue subsequent animations http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The callback will fire whenever the animation is complete.

Comment: In this case I have about 10 seconds of no animation, so I was trying to figure out how to queue that in there.

Comment: Ah - no worries then, atleast it's another thing to store away somewhere :)